# In XE2 how do you find unused private methods?

Tags: delphi, methods

I am used to unused methods giving hints and having no blue dot in the gutter. But that is not happening. I have just moved a large number of methods from a form unit to another, expecting the hints to find them so I could avoid the danger of cutting them out then finding I would need them.

But I have no hints, and the unused methods have blue dots. This is probable bound to be because of the new introspection. Which I don't like.

Comment: are you building in release mode or debug mode? The blue dots only appear when you are building in debug mode.

Answer (score 6):

If new style RTTI is enabled then, potentially all code is reachable through introspection. So you cannot rely on the compiler to find unused private. As far is it knows, the code may be called.

If you don't need new style RTTI then you can disable it to restore the behaviour you are used to. There are many questions here on SO that explain how to do that.

If you do need RTTI then you must rely on static analysis, and knowledge of your introspection code. The static analysis can range from a simple manual text search to a third party code parser/analyzer tool.